# Hat Overflow - Show number of Winterbash hats at a glance

Tags: script, users, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, winterbash

This script adds a Winterbash hat-count to every user "Signature block" on questions, answers, review pages, etc. For example:

[image: Added hat counts]

Reference this feature request: [Show hat count in user card (next to badges)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245319/show-hat-count-in-user-card-next-to-badges).

---

**To install**, click [here (Hatoverflow.user.js install at Github)](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/d54dfda1c9ba7434209d/raw/hatoverflow.user.js).

**To preview the source**, click [here (Hatoverflow.user.js preview at Github)](https://gist.github.com/BrockA/d54dfda1c9ba7434209d).

This userscript requires an engine that supports both `@require` and `GM_xmlhttpRequest`.  It was *tested* on **Firefox + Greasemonkey** and **Chrome + Tampermonkey**.

---

Notes and known issues:

1. **Quick-checked for December 2016.**  Seems to still work with no errors; let me know otherwise.
2. No attempt is made to distinguish between users with no hats and
   users not participating in Winterbash.
3. **Results are cached** for up to 2 hours.  This is to avoid hammering the API and tempting the API developers to hammer back.  A two-hour update rate is more than fast enough for hat coveting. ;)
4. Only the standard, mostly static, signatures as found on: questions, answers, review pages, etc., are supported or modified.  Question lists are not.
5. The script turns "off" unless it's December or January, but I recommend that you uninstall or disable the script when Winter Bash is not in effect.
6. Uses the undocumented Winterbash API, so it's subject to change without notice.
7. In some cases, the badge display might get clipped on the right side.  This is "won't fix", for now.