# App without API and legal issues

Tags: discussion, meta, legal

Forgive me I did not find the "meta" for the Stack Apps, I believe it is here that I must ask.

I developed an extension for browsers, but I'm not using the Stack Exchange API. Can I post it on Stack Apps?

The extension accesses data from [stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts](http://stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts)

Is creating an application without using the API allowed?

Comment: Stack Apps is Main and Meta at the same time :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can post extensions here that don't use the API.  There are several scripts/extensions/apps posted here that use [undocumented interfaces<sup>(example)</sup>](https://stackapps.com/questions/5056/hat-overflow-show-number-of-winterbash-hats-at-a-glance) or even [screen scraping<sup>(example)</sup>](https://stackapps.com/q/2982/7653).

The extension [must make use of the API and/**or enhance one or more Stack Exchange sites**](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic).

Reference:

1. [Stack Exchange APIs Terms of Use](http://stackexchange.com/legal/api-terms-of-use) (Still applies, for the most part)
2. [Etiquette of Screen-scraping Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow)
3. [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service)
4. [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](http://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance)

---

### You should use the API for your data as much as possible.

This *theoretically* avoids undocumented changes and staves off the ban-hammer.

In this case, you are fetching unread counts of notifications and inbox items.
There are existing API routes for both:

- [/inbox/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread)
  and
- [/notifications/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unread-notifications)

Ideally you would use these and not [that URL](http://stackexchange.com/topbar/get-unread-counts).  Although it can be quite a bother in this case, since both routes require OAuth and an `access_token`.
However, the URL might also yield unexpected results if the extension user is not authenticated and depending on how the extension calls it (It mostly reads as all zeroes, falsely, when not called as expected by the server).